# Make TMUX active whenever I start a new shell session on OSX

Tags: macos, bash, shell, tmux

I'm trying to start tmux automatically whenever I open a new shell, just note I'm using iTerm on OSX, I've tried putting the following in my .bashrc file:

```
if [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    exec tmux
fi
```

this doesn't work, though I've tested it on Ubuntu and it works just fine.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

with your codes, what happens if you start 10 terminals?

you can check the output of `tmux list-sessions` to decide if tmux has already started.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my .bashrc file wasn't loaded properly off the .bash_profile so I just had to move my scripts and settings to .bash_profile